# Resolve complex types using Typescript AST

Tags: typescript, abstract-syntax-tree

I'm attempting to extract complex types present within my TypeScript codebase. Utilizing the TypeScript checker, I've been able to successfully extract types; however, I've encountered difficulty when it comes to types nested within arrays.

I've made attempts to address this issue using TypeScript checker functionalities. You can find the current implementation here: [Link to the code](https://stackblitz.com/edit/node-xzthhl?file=index.ts,tsconfig.json,file-with-types.ts).

Currently, the code successfully extracts nested types when they are directly associated, as seen in the case of PrettyNestedType. However, it fails to capture nested types when they are within arrays, as demonstrated in the SomethingElse type, which contains an array of PrettyNestedType.

The expected output should resemble the following:

```
[ 'NestedObjectType', 'SomethingElse', 'PrettyNestedType', 'Imask' ]
```

but this is only working if i have PrettyNestedType associated without array of items like

```
type SomethingElse = {
  value2: PrettyNestedType;
};
```

source file

```
type NestedObjectType = {
  value1: string;
  value2: number;
  value3: Date;
  value4: SomethingElse;
};

type SomethingElse = {
  value2: PrettyNestedType[];
};

type PrettyNestedType = {
  value1: string;
  value2: number;
  value3: Date;
  test: Imask;
};

interface Imask {
  hello: string;
}

interface MainObjectType {
  value1: string;
  value2: number;
  value3: Date;
  propertyWithTypeAlias: NestedObjectType;
}
```

there is big question comes into my mind, how to handle union types associated, this is also complex part i think

Comment: Can explain from where the expected outcome comes from?

Comment: it should come from sourceFile, in reality i do have source file with lot of types, interfaces, enums and i do have identifier to grab all associated types with in (ex: MainObjectType)

Comment: this is working https://stackblitz.com/edit/node-xzthhl?file=index.ts,tsconfig.json,file-with-types.ts need to test more

Comment: So what you want to do is to have types/interfaces declared in a file and extract the name of some of them? Why only of those 4 and not of the `MainObjectType`?

Comment: need to extract what ever user defined types in MainObjectType, inside MainObjectType we do have complex type NestedObjectType and then NestedObjectType => SomethingElse etc..

Comment: Your code already extracts the following: `Associated types: [ 'NestedObjectType', 'SomethingElse', 'PrettyNestedType', 'Imask' ]`, what is missing?

Comment: yo, it's working after i changed https://stackblitz.com/edit/node-xzthhl?file=index.ts,tsconfig.json,file-with-types.ts but will test more with union types and resolve it and looking better approach to find nested types